# Slick2D AlphaMapTest Running

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I am trying to make a simple state based game with silck2d and whenever I run this simple code which should create an empty window (nothing but basic shells for the states so far).  Instead, it runs the AlphaMapTest program which I never called...

```
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Plane extends StateBasedGame {

public static final String gamename = "Plane Game";
public static final int MENU = 1;
public static final int PLAY = 2;

public Plane(String gamename) {
    super(gamename);
    addState(new Menu(MENU));
    addState(new Play(PLAY));
}

@Override
public void initStatesList(GameContainer container) throws SlickException {
    getState(MENU).init(container, this);
    getState(PLAY).init(container, this);
    enterState(PLAY);
}

public void main(String[] args) {
    AppGameContainer appgc;
    try {
        appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Plane(gamename));
        appgc.setDisplayMode(600, 400, false);
        appgc.start();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this in eclipse? Regardless, make sure you are actually compiling the right project. Should be selectable drop down menu around the "make/compile and run" button.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, yes the run configuration for the project was pointing to a test class as the main class...

Comment: Glad I could help! I've done that a few times myself haha I always think eclipse likes to mess with us sometimes, just to keep programmers on their toes.